# systemd-coredump service fills /run/systemd/propagate until out of inodes

Tags: systemd, core-dump

On my SUSE Linux, huge amount of coredump service directories were observed under `/run/systemd/propagate/`, sample as below, as of now `/run` has been totally filled with those folders without any free inode at all.

```
drw------- 2 root root 40 Nov 22 13:07 systemd-coredump@1917140-101884-0.service
drw------- 2 root root 40 Nov 22 13:07 systemd-coredump@1917141-102015-0.service
drw------- 2 root root 40 Nov 22 13:07 systemd-coredump@1917142-102088-0.service
drw------- 2 root root 40 Nov 22 13:07 systemd-coredump@1917155-102651-0.service
drw------- 2 root root 40 Nov 22 13:07 systemd-coredump@1917156-102733-0.service
```

Ideally these folders are supposed to be released by `systemd`.

How can I prevent them from remaining here?

- service unit:

  ```shellsession
  # cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-coredump@.service
  ```

  ```ini
  [Unit]
  Description=Process Core Dump
  Documentation=man:systemd-coredump(8)
  DefaultDependencies=no
  Conflicts=shutdown.target
  After=systemd-journald.socket
  Requires=systemd-journald.socket
  Before=shutdown.target

  [Service]
  ExecStart=-/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump
  IPAddressDeny=any
  LockPersonality=yes
  MemoryDenyWriteExecute=yes
  Nice=9
  NoNewPrivileges=yes
  OOMScoreAdjust=500
  PrivateDevices=yes
  PrivateNetwork=yes
  PrivateTmp=yes
  ProtectControlGroups=yes
  ProtectHome=yes
  ProtectHostname=yes
  ProtectKernelModules=yes
  ProtectKernelTunables=yes
  ProtectKernelLogs=yes
  ProtectSystem=strict
  RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_UNIX
  RestrictNamespaces=yes
  RestrictRealtime=yes
  RestrictSUIDSGID=yes
  RuntimeMaxSec=5min
  StateDirectory=systemd/coredump
  SystemCallArchitectures=native
  SystemCallErrorNumber=EPERM
  SystemCallFilter=@system-service
  ```

Comment: stupid question. Why are there so many coredumps? What service is crashing there?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks the suggestion, turns out that it was caused by a kubernetes pod which is crashing super fast.